# How to write a mysql prepared SELECT statement in python 3 using LIMIT?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.6

```
idValue = 100
limitValue = 10000
query = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM oneTable WHERE id = (%s) LIMIT (%s)";
cursor.execute(query, (idValue, limitValue ))
```

This doesn't seem to be working. It fetches only 1 record corresponding to the id.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this should work as you want. If you print result, you can see result of your query.

```
idValue = 100
limitValue = 10000
query = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM oneTable WHERE id = {0} limit {1}".format(idValue,limitValue)
cursor.execute(query)
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: it's not working. It does the same thing as above, fetches only 1 row. Any idea why?

Comment: there should be one row that id = 1000, i think you should try to remove id filter.

Answer (score 1):

The original query in the question does work. There was some other bug in my code and hence it ceased to work then. Thanks @Baran